# Is it possible to define sheet name as variable in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code for copying data from one sheet to another

```
Sub test1()

' test1 Macro

' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+S

ActiveCell.Select
Sheets("Athens Limestone Hospital").Select
ActiveCell.Range("A1:E2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

End Sub

---

Athens LimeStone Hospital is the sheet name, from which data is to be copied. Is it possible to define the sheet name as variable so as to make user give the sheet name he likes, without disturbing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, you have many options to let the user to select the ***SheetName***, see in code below:

```
Dim SheetName           As String
' option 1 - via inputbox
SheetName = InputBox("Please enter worksheet name", "Enter worksheet Name")

' option 2 - from Cell A1 in "Sheet1" >> you can modify to your needs
SheetName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

Sheets(SheetName).Select
```